# objective c Take picture in Camera API Phone Gap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am working in phonegap Camera API new to objective c i dont know  how to declare method and interface for this function in .h file

```
if([(NSString *) [components objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"Take_Photo"])    
  {
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self; 
            picker.allowsImageEditing = YES; 
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
```

I've declared `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in `.h` file but the camera is not opening. 
i did not get any error when i debugging the application paused after completed the line

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

the application debugger paused in the binary file. i think i missed something in .h file.

```
 @interface NativeAPI :UIViewController        
  <UIWebViewDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
   {

        Reachability* internetReachable;
        Reachability* hostReachable; 
         UIImagePickerController* Image_Picker;
    }
```

any one help me thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing like UIImageControllerDelegate here in the above code posted. Please provide the code for the implementation and header file here so that solution can be suggested.

Comment: "but it did not working" please be more specific. what did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be required to assign the value of the picker to the instance variable like this.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.Image_picker = picker;
[picker release];
Image_picker.delegate = self; 
Image_picker.allowsImageEditing = YES; 
Image_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Try the code above

You can define a method under the implementation which is to be called by the delegate.